# Set values of multiple child elements at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have this:

```
<div class="person">
    <div class="firstname"></div>
    <div class="lastname"></div>
    <div class="age"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to set the values of all the child elements at once with jQuery? Maybe something like this:

```
$('.person').xxx('.firstname', function(){
    $(this).text('John');
}).xxx('.lastname', function(){
    $(this).text('Smith');
}).xxx('.age', function(){
    $(this).text('12');
});
```

Or any other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're married to the idea of chaining everything, as your code seems to suggest, check out `jQuery.prototype.end()`...

```js
$(".person") // root selector
  .find(".firstname").text("john")
  .end() // back to person
  .find(".lastname").text("doe")
  .end()  // back to person
  .find(".age").text("18");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="person">
    <div class="firstname"></div>
    <div class="lastname"></div>
    <div class="age"></div>
</div>
```

This makes no assumptions about the position of the child nodes relative to eachother.

Alternatively, if you're sure that all of these items share the same parent, you could use `jQuery.prototype.siblings()`:

```js
$(".person")
  .find(".firstname").text("john")
  .siblings(".lastname").text("doe")
  .siblings(".age").text("18");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="person">
  <div class="firstname"></div>
  <div class="lastname"></div>
  <div class="age"></div>
</div>
```

To be honest, you're not gaining anything over targeting those items explicitly. If anything, it's less efficient.

Answer (score 5):

Very close, store person, and find the relative elements and set them.

```
var $person = $('.person');
$person.find('.firstname').text('John');
$person.find('.lastname').text('Smith');
$person.find('.age').text('12');
```

Or write your own:

```
$.fn.with = function(elems,selector,action){ 
return this.each(function(){
    $(elems).find(selector).each( function(i,e) {
      action(e)});
});
```

Then you could:

```
$('.person')
  .with('.firstname', function(e) { e.text('john'); })
  .with('.lastname', function(e) { e.text('Smith'); })
  .with('.age', function(e) { e.text('12'); })
```

I haven't writen jquery extensions recently, so it probably could be improved in a way to do it almost exactly as you have written it.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner solution:

```js
$(".person").children().text("john").next().text("doe").next().text("18");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="person">
    <div class="firstname"></div>
    <div class="lastname"></div>
    <div class="age"></div>
</div>
```

If you need it you can specify the realtive class name in children()/next() methods:

```
$(".person").children(".firstname").text("john").next(".lastname").text("doe").next(".age").text("18");
```

Comment: It's worth warning future readers that this solution is very dependent upon the order of the elements. So, any change to the order of the elements in the markup will also require a corresponding code change...